# What post-Snow Leopard OS upgrades are supported by a 2006 iMac iSight?

Tags: macos

I have a 2006 iMac iSight ["Core 2 Duo" 2.16 20-Inch Specs
Identifiers: Late 2006 - MA589LL - iMac5,1 - A1207 - 2118] w/250GB/Snow Leopard 10.6.8. What is the newest OS that will work? I have the Snow Leopard installation disk. What is the newest OS upgrade that I can get (download?) free?

Comment: Did you check the minimum specs for the OSs?

Comment: Everymac is your go-to source for that kind of info. Answer 10.7.5 - http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.16-20-inch-specs.html